# How can I adjust the vertical position of \nolimits?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, superscripts

I’m using the `newpx` fonts, but I want to lower the superscript after `\int` (i.e. after `\nolimits`) mainly in text style and maybe in display style too. Is this possible?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxmath}

\makeatletter
   \AtBeginDocument{
      \check@mathfonts
      \fontdimen13\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen14\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
      \fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x$
\[\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

I know that the *minimum* shift is controlled by the font dimes, but it seems like I can’t minimize the value for limits of `\int` further (only rising it would work, but then only affects normal superscripts).

Comment: you might try including a `\vphantom{\textsize{A^2}}` in the lower limit.  (i haven't tried this.)  the extra height should have the effect of pushing the lower limit down.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: But that must be done for every single `\int` then … I’m looking for a global setting, to keep things simple and consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will break other things, but … I make `^` active and, if in math mode, I redefine it to shift the argument down, while preserving the current math style.

## FOR SUPERSCRIPTS

(as was actually asked by the OP)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,url}
\let\svss^
\catcode`^=\active %
\def^{\ifmmode\expandafter\svss\expandafter\bgroup\expandafter\lowerit\else\svss\fi}
\def\lowerit#1{\ThisStyle{\raisebox{-2\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}}\egroup}
\usepackage{newpxmath,newpxtext}
\makeatletter
   \AtBeginDocument{
      \check@mathfonts
      \fontdimen13\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen14\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
      \fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
   }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\centering
A\_B \url{A_B} $\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x$
\[\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\[\scriptstyle\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\[\scriptscriptstyle\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this lowers **all** superscripts and I haven't yet found a way to limit its scope to, for example, `\int`.

This can be fixed by using an *if* set to true by `\int` and to false after usage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel,url}

\let\svss^
\catcode`^=\active %
\gdef^{\ifmmode\expandafter\svss\expandafter\bgroup\expandafter\lowerit\else\svss\fi}

% if to check wether an \int was preceding or not
\newif\ifAfterInt

\def\lowerit#1{%
   % lower superscript only if \int preceeded, then set
   % bool to false for all following superscripts until
   % the next \int sets it to true.
   \ifAfterInt
      \global\AfterIntfalse
      \ThisStyle{\raisebox{-2.5\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}}\egroup
   \else
      #1\egroup
   \fi
}

\usepackage{newpxmath,newpxtext}

\makeatletter
   \AtBeginDocument{
      \check@mathfonts
      \fontdimen13\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen14\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
      \fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
   }
\makeatother

% redefine \int to set the boolean to true
% (must be done after newpxmath was loaded)
\def\int{
   \intop\AfterInttrue\nolimits
}

\begin{document}
\centering
A\_\^B \url{A_^B}

$\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x$

\[\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]

\[\int_A^{\text{B}} x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]

\[\scriptstyle\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]

\[\scriptscriptstyle\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## PROBLEMS

Although this solution works, it has some problems:

- There can’t be a prime `'` before `^`, i.e. `V'^2` must be typed as `V'{}^2`
- `\text` must be enclosed in braces: `V^{\text{txt}}`
- You can’t use `^` in `\pgfmathsetmacro` and the linke anymore
- It breaks `mhchem`’s `\ce{^{123}Xx}`

## METHOD FOR SUBSCRIPTS

(Original misreading of the question)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,url}
\let\svus_
\catcode`_=\active %
\def_{\ifmmode\expandafter\svus\expandafter\bgroup\expandafter\lowerit\else\svus\fi}
\def\lowerit#1{\ThisStyle{\raisebox{-2\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}}\egroup}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\makeatletter
   \AtBeginDocument{
      \check@mathfonts
      \fontdimen13\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen14\textfont2=3.5pt
      \fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
      \fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
   }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\centering
A\_B \url{A_B} $\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x$
\[\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\[\scriptstyle\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\[\scriptscriptstyle\int_A^B x_a x^b x_a^b \,\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this lowers **all** subscripts and I haven't yet found a way to limit its scope to, for example, `\int`. This can be fixed as shown above for superscripts.

Comment: You should probably load the package `newpxtext` as well, as it affects the look of items such as `\mathrm{d}` and `A\_B`.

Comment: @Mico: I load it in my real document but omitted it for the MWE ...

Comment: @Steven: But I wanted to lower the superscript, while the subscript should stay as is … ;-)

Comment: @Tobi Brain fart on my part.  I will try to adjust when I get the chance.

Comment: @Tobi see revised answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for you edit. Seems to work fine. I found another way to check if the superscript belongs to an `\int`: I use an If statement (instead of your `\limdrop`) and set the bool in `\int`; see: https://gist.github.com/tweh/e76d9810fbe29d976534998ba617d831. You may like to add this to your answer. :-)

Comment: Ah, and another problem you might want to mention. The normally working `^\text{t}` needs a pair of braces. (see my Gist too)

Comment: @Tobi I would be happy to include your version but am, at the moment, receiving compile errors and ugly looking results with `\usepackage{newpxmath,newpxtext}` (even on my original code).  I can avoid the problem by instead using `\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx}` but I hesitate to post a change when I can't achieve a smooth compilation.  Also, I am about to fall offline until Tuesday and so I will have a renewed look at that time.

Comment: @Tobi I certainly have no problem with you editing my answer, if that suits you.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: done :-) but it is strange that you can’T compile without errors on my system (up-to-date TeX Live, Mac OS X) it works fine.

Comment: @Tobi strange indeed.  I can at the office, but not on my home system.  Perhaps something is, in fact, out of date, but no time to check at the moment.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I had some problem when adding the code to my reals document to (missing endcsname error). Could “solve” it by moving the critical code to other lines, but couldn’t find out who the problem was …

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LuaLateX-based solution. It has two requirements for the way the input material be formatted: (a) the material in the lower and upper limits of integration must be encased in curly braces, and (b) the lower limit of integration must come before the upper limit of integration. (If either requirement isn't met, the Lua function won't perform its operations.)

- The amounts by which the lower limit of integration is shifted down and the upper limit of integration is shifted up is controlled by macros `\Tstrut` ("top strut") and `\Bstrut` ("bottom strut"), respectively.
- Two LaTeX macros, called `\ChangeIntOff` and `\ChangeIntOn`, are provided to switch the function off and back on. The default state is "on".

(AFAICT, the packages `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` don't work very well with LuaLaTeX. In the code below, I therefore load `TeX Gyre Pagella` as the text font and `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` as the math font.)

The following screenshot shows that the solution affects inline-style integral expressions but not display-style integral expressions. The lines are there to help the eye decide how far the limits of integration have been shifted down and up, respectively (if at all, of course).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Set the dimensions of the top and bottom struts
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{1.65ex}}
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.85ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function change_int ( s ) 
   s = string.gsub ( s , "\\int%s-%_%s-(%b{})%s-^%s-(%b{})", 
            "\\int_{\\mkern-2mu %1\\Tstrut}^{%2\\Bstrut}")
   return s
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\ChangeIntOn{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", 
   change_int , "change_int" )}}
\newcommand\ChangeIntOff{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( "process_input_buffer",
   "change_int" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\ChangeIntOn} % function is on by default

\begin{document}

\hrule 
$\int _{A} ^{B} f(x)\,dx$ 
vs.\ 
$\int _A ^ {B} f(x)\,dx$ % not affected by Lua function b/c no curly braces around "A"
\hrule 

\bigskip
\hrule
$\displaystyle\int _ {A} ^ {B} f(x)\,dx$
vs.\ 
$\displaystyle\int _ A ^ {B} f(x)\,dx$
\hrule

\end{document}
```